# I don't know what's wrong with the do-while loop

Tags: java, loops, do-while

I want to make the program so that when the user presses a number which ISN'T between 1-10 it loops again; it runs again.  Note:  the cases are between String number and default

```
do {
    String responded;
    responded = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Do you understand do while loops?");
    String number = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Choose a number between 0 & 9 to generate \nthe corresponding word to that number or \npress 10 to exit the program");

                default:
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please make sure the number inserted is between 0 & 10.", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}
    } while (responded.equalsIgnoreCase("No"));
```

Comment: You are expecting the compiler to magically know that ``String number`` should be in the range ``"0"``..``"9"`` (``"10"``). ``default:`` is a label from a ``switch`` structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String responded;
       do{
         responded = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Do you understand do while loops?");
         boolean legitimate = false;
         do {
             String number = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Choose a number between 0 & 9 to generate \nthe corresponding word to that number or \npress 10 to exit the program");
             switch(number) {
             case "0" :
             case "1" :
             case "2" :
             case "3" :
             case "4" :
             case "5" :
             case "6" :
             case "7" :
             case "8" :
             case "9" : legitimate = true;
                        break;
             default:
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please make sure the number inserted is between 0 & 10.", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                 break;
             }
     } while(!legitimate);
} while (responded.equalsIgnoreCase("No"));
```

}

Comment: Thanks mate it works but when i choose a number from 0-9 the program just closes...

Comment: U said in your question that you want this to loop only if number entered is not in between 0 to 10. Thats why program closes when u said anything other than "no" to the first question and provides correct number

Comment: I meant in a different prespective lol...this is a Guesstheword program...there's is an array above all that which 10 different words labelled from 0-9 which works perfectly...lett me try an explain it with different words....the program is supposed to let the user choose a number between 0-10(10 being the number that lets the user exits the program)..before u gave me this code, when the user entered a number other than 0-10 the program just closes...i want the program to repeat the loop until the user enters a number from 1-10...i dont want the program to close when the user enters 1-9

Comment: You understand what im trying to say bro?

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with your brackets:

```
}
    } while (responded.equalsIgnoreCase("No"));
```

You need:

```
    } while (responded.equalsIgnoreCase("No"));
}
```

Also why do you have this `default:` there

Comment: The default is there so that when the user enters any other number other than 0-10 it shows the warning and its still not working for some reason...

Comment: It is still giving me errors on the lines:

    } while (responded.equalsIgnoreCase("No"));
         }
}
}

Comment: I'm new to this website to I'm kinda crap at using it atm

Answer (score 0):

Although I did nt understand your requirements completely but based on my understanding of what your requirements are , please find the code below :

```
    String responded;
     do{
         responded = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Do you understand do while loops?");
         boolean legitimate = true;
         do {
             String number = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Choose a number between 0 & 9 to generate \nthe corresponding word to that number or \npress 10 to exit the program");
             switch(number) {
             case "0" :
             case "1" :
             case "2" :
             case "3" :
             case "4" :
             case "5" :
             case "6" :
             case "7" :
             case "8" :
             case "9" : 
                 break;
             default:
                 legitimate = false;
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please make sure the number inserted is between 0 & 10.", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                 break;
             }
         } while(legitimate);
     } while (responded.equalsIgnoreCase("No"));
```

Comment: Now when I put in any number which isn't between 0-10 the program gives me an error than closes

Comment: U want to stay in loop when number entered is between 0 - 9 or do you want to stay in loop when number entered is not in the range(0-9).

Comment: When entered between 0-9